# ChartJS: Is this horizontal stacked bar and line graph multiaxis chart even possible?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to setup a graph that looks somewhat like this:

[image]
The graph consists of two data series, one for the stacked and another for the averages. Pay attention that is has two x-axis (multiaxis).

Looking at the ChartJS documentation, [mixed graph types are possible](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/mixed.html), but not for stacked horizontal bars. Other articles seem to outline this as well, [like this one on Alligator.io](https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-chart-js/#mixed-charts). I've yet to see any chart library to showcase such an example even.

Question is therefore if this is even possible, or if I should look into alternate approaches instead.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Have you? (Also, the answer is no as this is a screen capture from an excel doc).

Comment: Yep. Seems doable at first blush. Good luck.

Comment: Actually, I have tried. Several times over. It's not something that's possible with ChartJS or any other surfaceable Chart libraries this side of Mercur. If you think it's doable, I urge you to try your hand at it (even though you'll most likely reach the same conclusion).

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible ([only proof I could find right now](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4047)).

The next version of chart.js will be [3.0 which has many major impovements](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/6598), including changes to the horizontal bar chart, verbatim "Remove horizontalBar and make all charts capable of being horizontal". I think it will be possible with this version. But unfortunately not now.

Comment: There is one lead to go on, but it doesn't seem very manageable: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4096#issuecomment-434943049

Comment: Yes. I found that too but didn't think it's worth noting.